# Compare Data of DB2 and SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, db2, database-migration

I have two Databases with identical schema and object but with different data. The DBs are on two separate servers:

One is DB2 on MainFrame (OS 360) with 300+ tables

The other one is SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need any tool, software, package, script batch, actually anything that can help me throughout these tasks:

> Find the records in DB2 but not in SQL Server.
>
> Find the records that are in that Updated.
>
> Make SQL Server's data identical to that of DB2

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do all of this with SQL Server Integration Services and the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/), a tool that is designed to do such diffs. You can output all of your schema details into a human-readable text file. You can also output the data from your tables in CSV files, or even run arbitrary SELECT statements. Then, you can compare the data using a standard diff tool. SchemaCrawler is a free, open-source tool, and is cross-platform.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler